# Spring Boot data JPA persistence to database error

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm doing a project with spring boot data jpa. Jobs, Country, Departments and Employee tables. I wrote a method with the controller and created and associated objects manually. However, I did not encounter any errors when I ran my application, but no records were added to my database and my tables were not created. What could be the reason? I share my codes with you below. Thank you.

[project structure](https://ibb.co/ZMQfnk1)

**JOBS**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="jobs")
public class Jobs {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @NotNull
    @Column
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String title;

    @Column
    private int salary;

    @Column
    private String currency;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Departments> departments;

    //G&S
}
```

**COUNTRY**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="country")
public class Country {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @NotNull
    @Column
    private int id;

    @NotNull
    @Column
    private String country;

    @NotNull
    @Column
    private String city;

    @NotNull
    @Column
    private String district;

    //G&S
}
```

**DEPARTMENTS**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "departments")
public class Departments {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @NotNull
    @Column
    private int id;

    @NotNull
    @Column
    private String department;

    @OneToMany
    private Country country;

    //G&S
}
```

**EMPLOYEE**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="employee")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @NotNull
    @Column
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String firstName;

    @Column
    private String lastName;

    @OneToMany
    private Jobs jobs;

    //G&S
}
```

**JOBS, COUNTRY, DEPARMENTS AND EMPLOYEE REPOSITORIES ARE JPA REPOSITORY**

**EMPLOYEE REPOSITORY**

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Integer>{

}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
@RestController

public class MainController {

    @Autowired
    JobsRepository jobsRepository;

    @Autowired
    CountryRepository countryRepository;

    @Autowired
    DepartmentsRepository departmentsRepository;

    @Autowired
    EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    Jobs jobs;
    Country country;
    Departments departments;
    Employee employee;
    List<Departments> departmentsList;


    @GetMapping("/generate")
    public String generateManual() {

        try {
            country = new Country();
            country.setCountry("Turkey");
            country.setCity("Istanbul");
            country.setDistrict("Pendik");
            countryRepository.save(country);

            departments = new Departments();
            departments.setDepartment("IT");
            departments.setCountry(country);
            departmentsRepository.save(departments);

            jobs = new Jobs();
            jobs.setTitle("Software Developer");
            jobs.setSalary(4000);
            jobs.setCurrency("TL");
            departmentsList = new ArrayList<Departments>();
            jobs.setDepartments(departmentsList);
            jobsRepository.save(jobs);

            employee = new Employee();
            employee.setFirstName("Mutlu");
            employee.setLastName("EREN");
            employee.setJobs(jobs);
            employee.setJobs(jobs);
            employeeRepository.save(employee);

                return "GENERATED SUCCESSFULLY";

            }catch(Exception e) {
                return "FAILED";
            }           
    }
}
```

**APP PROPERTIES**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jobs?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=Turkey
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

**SPRING LOG**

```
2019-09-18 12:41:11.375  INFO 28594 --- [           main] com.example.sec.JobsApplication          : Starting JobsApplication on meren-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC with PID 28594 (/home/meren/Documents/workspace-sts-3.9.9.RELEASE/jobs/target/classes started by meren in /home/meren/Documents/workspace-sts-3.9.9.RELEASE/jobs)
2019-09-18 12:41:11.378  INFO 28594 --- [           main] com.example.sec.JobsApplication          : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-09-18 12:41:12.082  INFO 28594 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-09-18 12:41:12.108  INFO 28594 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 12ms. Found 0 repository interfaces.
2019-09-18 12:41:12.442  INFO 28594 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d99ff66a] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-09-18 12:41:12.706  INFO 28594 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-09-18 12:41:12.736  INFO 28594 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-09-18 12:41:12.736  INFO 28594 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.24]
2019-09-18 12:41:12.819  INFO 28594 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-09-18 12:41:12.819  INFO 28594 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1402 ms
2019-09-18 12:41:12.991  INFO 28594 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2019-09-18 12:41:13.092  INFO 28594 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2019-09-18 12:41:13.126  INFO 28594 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2019-09-18 12:41:13.164  INFO 28594 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.11.Final}
2019-09-18 12:41:13.164  INFO 28594 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2019-09-18 12:41:13.257  INFO 28594 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
2019-09-18 12:41:13.340  INFO 28594 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2019-09-18 12:41:13.516  INFO 28594 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-09-18 12:41:13.721  INFO 28594 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-09-18 12:41:13.751  WARN 28594 --- [           main] aWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2019-09-18 12:41:13.926  INFO 28594 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2019-09-18 12:41:13.928  INFO 28594 --- [           main] com.example.sec.JobsApplication          : Started JobsApplication in 2.886 seconds (JVM running for 3.508)
2019-09-18 12:41:19.393  INFO 28594 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-09-18 12:41:19.393  INFO 28594 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-09-18 12:41:19.409  INFO 28594 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 16
```

**http://localhost:8080/generate**

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Sep 18 16:05:28 EET 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

Comment: So when you called `/generate`, what was returned? You should be printing the stacktrace when you get an exception, that way you have a way to know what went wrong and fix it.

Comment: @Kayaman i just added to the bottom

Comment: can you plz check mysql-connector jar file it's available in maven build? and check which database you are using because in spring boot have default database is H2

Comment: @okoreni put `e.printStackTrace()` in your catch block (or `logger.error(e)` if you have a Logger configured). That way you'll see the actual exception stacktrace. Now you're just seeing the 404 for the missing error page.

Comment: @BheemSingh my dependencies are correct, i cant fnd the where is the mistake

Comment: @okoreni plz can u check Database name

Answer (score 0):

With your code, the records will be added only when you do a `GET /generate`, so it's normal that your database is empty when you run the application.
If you want to preload the database with some records, I suggest the creation of a configuration class like this :

```
@Configuration
public class LoadDatabase {

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner initDatabase(MyRepository repository) {
        return args -> {
            repository.save(...);
        };
    }
}
```

This way you will not have to make a request to your API each time you want to generate your database.

Answer (score 0):

From your description i understood you have two issues.

1) DB Tables not getting created.

I had same issue and i tried by changing my db config like this has solved db creation issue.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDbSchema?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.profiles.active=prod
```

2) This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Here spring boot is trying to look for page named as 'error'. So that means I think  you are using Spring MVC. so if any error occur at runtime, MVC view resolver will look for error page.

and your error message also showing "There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404)." so i am suspecting that it is trying to look for page named as "GENERATED SUCCESSFULLY" for no exception case or "Failed" for exception case and it does not find that page that is why it gives error code 404

If you want to just return plain string then change your get api like below.

```
@GetMapping("/generate")
public ResponseEntity<String> generateManual() {

    try {
        country = new Country();
        country.setCountry("Turkey");
        country.setCity("Istanbul");
        country.setDistrict("Pendik");
        countryRepository.save(country);

        departments = new Departments();
        departments.setDepartment("IT");
        departments.setCountry(country);
        departmentsRepository.save(departments);

        jobs = new Jobs();
        jobs.setTitle("Software Developer");
        jobs.setSalary(4000);
        jobs.setCurrency("TL");
        departmentsList = new ArrayList<Departments>();
        jobs.setDepartments(departmentsList);
        jobsRepository.save(jobs);

        employee = new Employee();
        employee.setFirstName("Mutlu");
        employee.setLastName("EREN");
        employee.setJobs(jobs);
        employee.setJobs(jobs);
        employeeRepository.save(employee);
            return new ResponseEntity<>("GENERATED SUCCESSFULLY", HttpStatus.OK);


        }catch(Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Failed", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }           
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that your controller method is not called at all.
(That's why you get a 404)

I believe it's not even registered by Spring.

Based on the project structure you provided your Spring Application main class is in the `com.example.sec` package while the other packages (including the controller package) are *NOT* under that package. By default Spring Boot only scans the subpackages of the application class for annotated classes/methods, so you basically runs an empty Spring boot application.
That also explains why yor tables are not created: Spring Boot didn't scan your entities neither.

Move your main class into the `com.example` package.

After you fix that you will propbably have some JPA exceptions.

When you save an object using save(object) it *RETURNS* the persisted object. So you need to add the returned object as a property to the parent object, not the original one.

The simplest (but not the nicest) solution if you override the original one:

```
country = countryRepository.save(country);
...
departments = departmentsRepository.save(departments);
...
```

The 3rd problem is your class variables in the MainController. Although it's only a test project, it's a extremely dangerous practice. `jobs`, `country`, `departments`,... should be local variables in the controller method.